# Count or Sum using Pandas Dataframe with number of columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

im trying to find a way to find the count of the number of rows for a dataframe.

here is my df

```
 index col1  col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8
  0     1     0    2    3     1    0   0    0
  1     0     0    0    1     2    0   2    0
  2     3     0    0    0     1    0   0    1
  3     1     0    0    0     1    1   1    0
  4     1     0    2    3     1    0   0    0
  5     3     0    0    0     1    0   0    1
```

here i would like to append another row for count of my columns  such as below

```
index col1  col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8
  0     1     0    2    3     1    0   0    0
  1     0     0    0    1     2    0   2    0
  2     3     0    0    0     1    0   0    1
  3     1     0    0    0     1    1   1    0
  4     1     0    2    3     1    0   0    0
  5     3     0    0    0     1    0   0    1
-----------------------------------------------
Total   5     0    2    3     6    1   2    2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) of `boolean mask` created by comparing with `0`. Output assign by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to last row of `DataFrame`:

```
print (df != 0)
        col1   col2   col3   col4  col5   col6   col7   col8
index                                                       
0       True  False   True   True  True  False  False  False
1      False  False  False   True  True  False   True  False
2       True  False  False  False  True  False  False   True
3       True  False  False  False  True   True   True  False
4       True  False   True   True  True  False  False  False
5       True  False  False  False  True  False  False   True

df.loc['total'] = (df != 0).sum()
print (df)
       col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7  col8
index                                                
0         1     0     2     3     1     0     0     0
1         0     0     0     1     2     0     2     0
2         3     0     0     0     1     0     0     1
3         1     0     0     0     1     1     1     0
4         1     0     2     3     1     0     0     0
5         3     0     0     0     1     0     0     1
total     5     0     2     3     6     1     2     2
```

Similar solution with [`DataFrame.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html):

```
df.loc['total'] = df.ne(0).sum()
print (df)
       col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7  col8
index                                                
0         1     0     2     3     1     0     0     0
1         0     0     0     1     2     0     2     0
2         3     0     0     0     1     0     0     1
3         1     0     0     0     1     1     1     0
4         1     0     2     3     1     0     0     0
5         3     0     0     0     1     0     0     1
total     5     0     2     3     6     1     2     2
```